# It seems i can't use a function inside another function

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to build a little short path problem
I succesfully created the nodes as objects, defined the starting one and the final one with dedicated functions and computed(with a dedicated function) the neighbors inside a radius for any given node using an euclidean distance(dedicated function as well)

I'm sure the neighbors function, where nodes is a list nodes and node is the node of which i want to compute the neighboring nodes, works.

```
def neighbors(nodes,node):
    neighbors=[]
    for i in nodes:
        dist=distance(i,node)
        if dist<=15:
            neighbors.append(i)
    return neighbors
```

when i try and call the function to select a path from the starting node to the final node

```
def choose_path(final_node,starting_node,nodes):
    neighbors=neighbors(nodes,starting_node)
    more code
```

after i defined nodes and starting node, it raises an error: "local variable 'neighbors' referenced before assignment" and i can't understand why. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance to those who will help me!

Comment: you are using function name as variable names in many places change the variable names.

Comment: are @RajuKomati says - you need to rename your `neighbors` variables to something else as your function is already called `neighbors` - i.e. `items=[] items.append(i) return items` - same goes for `neighbors` in choose_path.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `neighbors()` and then assign the result to `neighbors`.

Don't use the same name for your variable as your function.